# Finding all "2 - Tiles" in a 2-d array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a 2-d array of integers, with the values of each index being either 0 or 1, and I need to count the number of 2 tiles in the array. For clarification, a 2 tiles is something like:

1 **0 1**

0 **0 1**

0 1 1

where adjacent rows/columns are of the opposite value. I have an idea of iterating through every index of the 2-d array and checking whether that indexes horizontal/vertical neighbours are of the same value (but not the diagonals), and if this is true then check the adjacent neighbours to see if they are of the opposing value. Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: which lang? what have you done so far?

Comment: @shahaf working in Java at the minute. I can get a list of all the 1s in the array and their row/column index.Just wondering what the simplest way to check the neighbouring values are without going into a half dozen if statements or so.

Comment: if I understand your description, it means every row or column should have a sum of 1 or 2 (2 * 0 + 1 = 1 or 2 * 1 + 0 = 2) - maybe iterate rows cols and checking for a sum of 1 or 2